# Javascript function: caps after comma

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that onkeydown(), forces all letters to be capitalized after a comma (",") in a text input field.

I know that I can make all of the letters capital using this function:

```
function makeUppercase(field) {
   field.value = field.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

But am not sure how to say to do this function only after a comma is present.

Answer (score 2):

regexps are good for things like that. something like

```
function makeUpperCaseAfterCommas(str) {
    return str.replace(/,\s*([a-z])/g, function(d,e) { return ", "+e.toUpperCase() });
}
```

Comment: What would I put onkeydown="" to trigger this function?

Comment: that's actually trickier than it seems. If you simply did something like onkeydown="this.value = makeUpperCaseAfterCommas(this.value)", it'd "work", but you'd probably lose your carret position after every key stroke in the input field. To handle that part is more complex, but http://parentnode.org/javascript/working-with-the-cursor-position/ should give you an idea of the approach to take.

Comment: this function only capitalizes the first letter after a comma, I need it to capitalize everything after a comma. any suggestions?

Comment: Oh sorry. I read your reqs too fast. Well, you can tweak the regexp to be /,\s*(.*)/ . That will grab absolutely everything after the first comma seen. If you only wanted to capitalize one word after each comma, you'd use /,\s*([a-z][A-Z]*)/g .

Answer (score 0):

I suppose one way to do it would be to do a test:

```
if (field.value.indexOf(',') == -1) // comma doesn't exist in the string
{
   // add the character
}
else
{
   // add the uppercase version of the character.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test for commas and if they exist split on comma. Anything after the first index of the new array apply the toUppercase to and then rejoin the string on comma and replace the input field with the reformed string.

```
function makeUppercase(field) {

   if(filed.value.indexOf(",") != -1)
   {
        var inputStr = field.value.split(",");
        for(var i = 1; i < inputStr.length; i++)
        {
            inputStr[i] = inputStr[i].toUpperCase();
        }
        field.value = inputStr.join(",");
   }
}
```